# Will azure devops handle feature branch pull request that was rebased on another feature branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a branch and another team member has his branch. His branch is not merging because something in CI Pipeline broke, and I need functionality from his branch to continue my work.
Can I rebase on his branch, and Pull request in azure devops will be still possible, both, if the other team member integrates his PR to main, and if he abandons?

Answer (score 1):

In git, *branches don't really exist* - that is, a branch isn't "a sequence of commits with some label" as it is in some other systems. Instead, a branch points to a *single commit*, at the "tip" of the branch, and git finds history by walking *backwards* through the "parents" of each commit. As such, "commits on branch X" are more accurately called "commits reachable from the tip labelled X".

The reason this is relevant is that when you raise a Pull Request to merge "everything on `feature-X` into `main`", git will try to merge *all commits reachable form `feature-X` which are not also reachable from `main`". Normally, this is a good way of identifying "the commits developed for feature X", because the commit graph looks something like this:

```
                -- C <-- D <-(feature-X)
               /
... <-- A <-- B <-(main)
               \
                -- E <-- F <-(feature-Y)
```

A PR for `feature-X` will select commits C and D, and a PR for `feature-Y` will select commits E and F.

But if you *rebase* one branch onto the other, you end up with a graph more like this:

```
... <-- A <-- B <-(main)
               \
                -- E <-- F <-(feature-Y)
                          \
                           -- C2 <-- D2 <-(feature-X)
```

If `feature-Y` doesn't get merged, and you raise a PR for `feature-X`, git will look for all the commits in the history of D2 (`feature-X`) which aren't in the history of B (`main`), and will find *E, F, C2, and D2*.

This probably makes sense: you needed work that your colleague had done, so that needs to be merged in somehow. On the other hand, if `feature-Y` was abandoned, there might be things in those commits which you *don't* want - maybe you really want F but not E; if so, you'll need to create a different version, and rebase onto that:

```
                -- F2 <-- C3 <-- D3 <-(feature-X)
               /
... <-- A <-- B <-(main)
               \
                -- E <-- F <-(feature-Y, abandoned)
```

If `feature-Y` gets merged first, all is fine *as long as `feature-Y` isn't rebased or "squashed"*; you'll have a graph like this:

```
... <-- A <-- B <--------- M <-(main)
               \          /
                -- E <-- F <-(feature-Y)
                          \
                           -- C2 <-- D2 <-(feature-X)
```

Now git will look for all the commits in the history of D2 (`feature-X`) which aren't in the history of M (`main`), and will find only C2 and D2 - E and F are already in the history of M.

Comment: What about squash commit? What happens?

Comment: @jjaskulowski A squash commit, like a rebase, means "create a brand new commit with no relationship to the original". If you squash E and F into a new commit S, then C and D will have no relationship with S whatsoever, but E and F will still exist. So, short answer: don't do that.